# Laravel 5.6 Bootstrap 4.0.0 package is not installed -- error in package.json

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I am new at Laravel 5.6

the bootstarb is not working ... when i check the `package.json` it gives me error in many packages say that it not installed including bootstrap 4.0.0

is that something wrong in composer !!??

that is my `package.json` file

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": { //all of them not installed

        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your issue please? It sounds like you are a little mixed up with composer and npm. This file has nothing to do with composer (which is for php dependencies). You should use `npm` install to install these packages

Comment: sorry i am new - my issue is bootstrap not working ... how to install npm ?

Comment: npm comes with node. Which you can find how to install here https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: done .... thank you so mush